# How are confidence intervals calculated for lm in R using predict?

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, linear-model

Here, a simple linear model, given x = 98, yields a predicted value of 24.47 with 95% confidence interval [23.97, 24.96].

```
> library(ISLR)
> linreg = lm(mpg ~ horsepower, data = Auto)
predict(linreg, data.frame(horsepower=c(98)), interval = 'confidence')
       fit      lwr      upr
1 24.46708 23.97308 24.96108
```

However, the confidence intervals through `confint` are as follows:

`> confint(linreg)
                2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) 38.525212 41.3465103
horsepower  -0.170517 -0.1451725`

Plugging in x = 98 yields a confidence interval of [21.81, 27.16].

Why are the two intervals different? How is the confidence interval through `predict` calculated?

Comment: Welcome to CV Brian. Maybe by explaning what is done in 'Pluggin in x =' you will find the solution. You are looking for a confidence interval on a linear function of the parameter *vector*.